# Changing response body of 301 from Apache 2.2

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm performing a simple redirect using an `.htaccess` file served from `Apache 2.2`, easy enough!

However, I want to change the response body that gets sent back from Apache. Currently the response body is as below but I'm looking to either modify this (or just get rid of it altogether).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
        <p>The document has moved 
            <a href="https://www.mynewlocation.com/">here</a>.
        </p>
        <hr>
        <address>Apache/2.2.34 (Amazon) Server at myoldlocation.com Port 80</address>
    </body>
</html>
```

For completeness the `.htaccess` file is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mynewlocation.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out assumption is a bad thing and after [reading the Apache doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/custom-error.html) I assumed this wouldn't work as a 301 isn't really an 'error'.

Turns out I just needed to modify my `.htaccess` file to have the following (an empty string threw a 500):

```
ErrorDocument 301 "301 Moved Permanently"

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mynewlocation.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Which gives me the simple output of `301 Moved Permanently`

Answer (score -1):

This should be a comment, but its a bit long hence posting here....

301 redirects are almost always the wrong way to fix a problem. Its probably wrong here too.

> The document has moved...www.mynewlocation.com...myoldlocation.com

Users don't read/type URLs they click on links and bookmarks. OTOH any browser which sees this 301 redirect will remember it for a while - even though you didn't set any cache expiry information, it will be stored in the cache. So if the users tries the URL they know in a different browser, they won't get to your site. If the users cache is overflowed (which is considered best practice for managing caching these days) they won't get to your site.

So other than for machine-to-machine communications, when migrating to a different scheme / hostname, its musch better to give a 200 response then run a javascript with a timer and redirect.

Comment: While caching of redirects can indeed be a nuisance, the correct fix is to either a) use a temporary redirect code (302 or 307); or b) send explicit cache headers. Your description of what will happen also makes no sense - if they use a new browser, or their cache overflows, the page will be requested, and they'll be served the redirect; the server would only stop serving the redirect if you changed the configuration - and that would be true with a fake JS redirect as well.

Comment: I've gone back and read the question a few times, along with the accepted self-answer, and your answer, and I think possibly _you_ misread the question. The HTML shown in the question isn't the _desired_ result, it's what Apache does by default _at the same time as_ sending a 301 status code (as it should, under the HTTP spec). I've still no idea what you're trying to describe regarding caching though, so maybe you could explain in more detail what you think I've missed.